# MySQL Connecting

Tags: mysql, connection, looker-studio

I have a MySQL db on A2 hosting. I can connect via terminal with no issues. I can also connect using Oracle workbench. But when I use the exact same creds on Google Data Studio and it says "Access denied, please check your username and password."

I even tried changing the password to 12345 just to test and it says the same thing.
I have tried using both the ip and the host name with no luck.

It is only on google data studio that I can not connect.

Comment: From the error message, you use incorrect username and password. Please check it correctly again.

Comment: Maybe the login credentials are correct but you have no permissions set to connect from outside of localhost. You should connect locally and check the permissions.

Answer (score 0):

So it ended up being a firewall setting in the hosting site that I did have to update.